# Getting "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple" when writing to a file

Tags: python

I'm creating a dice game in Python 3.7.2. I need to write the results to a text file but with my current code I'm getting errors.

I've tried just casting to a string but that just causes more issues.

```
file = open("dicegamescores.txt","w") 
x = str('on round',x,username1 ,'has',player1_score , '\n',username2'has', player2_score)
file.write(x) 
file.close
```

I expected the result of `('on round', x, username1 , 'has', player1_score , '\n' , username2 , 'has', player2_score )` to be written to the file with the correct variable values based on the iteration. Instead, I get one of the following two errors, depending on whether or not I cast the result to a string:

WHEN NOT CAST TO STR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joelb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\dicegame.py", line 45, in <module>
    file.write(x)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple
```

WHEN CAST TO STR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joelb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\dicegame.py", line 44, in <module>
    x = str('on round', x, username1 , 'has', player1_score , '\n' , username2 , 'has', player2_score )
TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (9 given)
```

Comment: You have to `.format()` your string; not cast it.

Comment: When you call `str()` with multiple arguments, it converts each argument to a string and returns all of them as a tuple, it doesn't concatenate them. Use string formatting instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey, you need to make the x variable in a string format.
You can use this code :**

```
file = open("dicegamescores.txt","w") 
x = ('on round',2,username1 ,'has',player1_score , '\n',username2,'has', player2_score)
xx = ("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s")%(x)
file.write(xx) 
file.close
```

**For every string in the variable you should add %s.**

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
x = 'on round {round} {user1} has {user1score} \n {user2} has {user2score}'.format(
round = x, user1 = username1, user1score = player1_score, user2= username2, user2score = player2_score)
```

with the `.format()` method you can insert values into placeholders i.e.`round`.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to write something to a file the way you do it has to be a string, so that is why the first one fails.
The second one fails, because (as the error says) you try to create a string out of the ungrouped elements. To make this work, the elements should be **one** array/list so Python can make a proper string out of it:

```
x = str(['on round',x,username1 ,'has',player1_score , '\n',username2'has', player2_score]) #See the square brackets
```

However the more pythonic way to do this would be:

```
x = "on round %s %s has %d \n %s has %d" % (x, username1, player1_score, username2, player2score)
```

*%s inserts a String, %d an integer, %f a float. See [Learn Python](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting) for an explanation on this.*